# Zend Framework 3 - connect two modules

Tags: php, zend-framework3

I'm playing around with Zend 3 and I have a question.

I'm building a small dashboard for creating and viewing time sheets. I have "sheet" entities and "client" entities.

The client pages are relatively easy, however I don't know how to program to do what I want with the sheet pages.

What I want to do is: I have a sheet entity with an id, a date, a time and a database column where the id of the client is saved. In the front end I now would like to display the client's name instead of the id.
But that means I have to use the getName() function of the client module.
Usually I would create a new Client and then just ask for the name.

However after having built my application with the Zend tutorial for blog posts, with all the factories and interfaces I don't know what instance to create and where I'd get the constructor variables from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there's several answers for this, but this's how i do it;

1: create a strategy for hydrator which takes client repository via __construct method. on "hydrate" method, get client data from repository and put it into sheet model

2: create a callable class with name "injectClient". on __invoke method take sheet as parameter. when you got it, ask to client repository for client of that sheet. you have to join two tables here. it's good for lazy loading. on first method, you have to load client data when you load sheet. but this one, you can just call it when you exactly need.

I'm using first answer for "must have to be there" data. Like language on multi-language applications. And second one for lazy-load.

Also you can use an object mapper like doctrine. It's always using lazy-load if you don't mention opposite.